# mongodb query: filter results by string attribute that is partly matched (filter string is subset of attribute string)

Tags: c#, mongodb

i want to query data from a mongoDB database and want to apply a filter to it. Stuff like this works fine:

```
var wantedAttributes = "word";
Collection.Find(Builders<MyModel>.Filter.Eq("Attributes", wantedAttributes)).ToList();
```

but only if my wantedAttributes match exactly to the Attributes field value in the db.
My usecase is that, the Attributes values are lists of strings, like:

```
word1, word2, word3
word2, word3, word1
word3, word1, word4
```

What i want is a method to get or match all entries that contain a given set of words, but not necessary in the same order. More words are allowed but not less!

So if my *wantedAttributes = word4* i want to get the third entry only and if my *wantedAttributes = word1,word2* i want the first and the second.

The wantedAttributes do not necessary has to be a string of comma separated words, but the database entries are.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var wanteds = "word4";
var filter = Builders<MyModel>.Filter.Empty;
foreach (var wanted in wanteds.Split(','))
{
    filter = filter & Builders<MyModel>.Filter.Where(m => m.Str.Contains(wanted.Trim()));
}
var models = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

My model:

```
class MyModel
{
    [BsonElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("str")]
    public string Str { get; set; }
}
```

You can customize the wanted string and string separator.

Answer (score 0):

since you asked the best way, i'd suggest storing the attributes as a string array instead of a string in the db and query like so:

```cs
    var wantedAttributes = new[] { "word1", "word2" };

    var result = collections.AsQueryable<MyModel>()
                   .Where(m => wantedAttributes.All(a => m.Attributes.Contains(a)))
                   .ToList();
```

this way you can index the `Attributes` field and get lightning fast results. the `m.Str.Contains(wanted.Trim())` method which @charles suggested will cause a regex match which will not be able to use an index. only prefixed regex queries can use indexes in mongodb.

here's full test program:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverFlow
{
    public class MyModel : Entity
    {
        public string[] Attributes { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            new DB("test");

            new[] {
                new MyModel{
                    Attributes = new[]{ "word1", "word2", "word3" }
                },
                new MyModel{
                    Attributes = new[]{ "word2", "word3", "word1" }
                },
                new MyModel{
                    Attributes = new[]{ "word3", "word1", "word4" }
                }
            }
            .Save();

            var wantedAttributes = new[] { "word1", "word2" };

            var result = DB.Queryable<MyModel>()
                           .Where(m => wantedAttributes.All(a => m.Attributes.Contains(a)))
                           .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```